# Trying to use C to have an ATTiny85 utilize Fast PWM to dim and brighten an LED over time. The code should be working but it is not

Tags: c, led, pwm

Trying to get an LED to fade on and off using Fast PWM on a AATiny85.  Have tried both configuring this to be on then shut off as well as using the for loop to gradually turn it back off.  The issue we have when we compile and program the code is when the code executes within the bread board, the LED simply blinks without any sort of change in frequency or brightness.  If the code was working correctly, the LED should gradually increase or decrease in brightness based on the current value of the value of the variable 'dutyCycle.'  Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
#define F_CPU 20000000   


#include <avr/io.h>    
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include <util/delay.h>


 double dutyCycle = 0;
 int d = 0;

 int main(void)
{
    DDRB = 1 << PORTB0;
    TCCR0A = (1 << COM0A1) | (1 << WGM00) | (1 << WGM01);

    TIMSK = (1 << TOIE0);
    OCR0A = (dutyCycle/100)*255;

    sei();

    TCCR0B = (1 << CS00) | (1 << CS02); // needs to be last or else clock starts

    while(1){
        _delay_ms(1000);
        dutyCycle += 10;
        if(dutyCycle > 100){
            dutyCycle = 0;
            for(d = 100; d >=0; d-=10){
                _delay_ms(10000);
                dutyCycle = (double)d;
            }
        }
    }
}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect) //what happens on overflow    (interrupt)
{
    OCR0A = (dutyCycle/100)*255;
}
```

Comment: Please provide `_delay_ms` and `sei`. Does `_delay_ms` use `dutyCycle`? Otherwise `dutyCycle` is unused, What are `DDRB` and the other variables? What are they used for?

Comment: Note that your for loop has a 10 second delay. If you are impatient, you don't see it change as it takes too long for you.

Comment: Don't use double if working with integers. The dutyCycle (0-255?) should be written to the appropriate register of the PWM hardware as soon as it changes; are you sure that OCR0A is the register for durty cycle, and that the PWM output is connected to the correct pin?

Comment: `_delay_ms` uses is from the library `interrupt.h` and simply delays the execution for a specified amount of miliseconds.  `dutyCycle` is supposed to change the relative voltage via fast PWM.  `DDRB` and the other variables are used to set values of `1` or `0` to each of the various pins of the chip.